# How to stagger I/O in python multiprocessing processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mpi

I will have 6 to 12 multiprocessing processes running independent Markov chain Monte Carlo runs to test different parameters. However, each of these runs has significant file I/O needs. I would like to prevent more than a set number of processes from using file I/O functions (that I wrote so I have control over the function itself) at a time.

Is this possible? I am familiar with MPI if that makes it easier, but that seems like overkill since I don't otherwise have any communication needs between the processes.

Comment: Have the main thread do all of the I/O and feed it the subprocesses (via a queue for example). You could go further and set up *n* threads (threads are generally fine for I/O limited functions) to do the I/O and feed it to the subprocesses.

Comment: @101 is that possible if each process has it's own personal save files and data files? There's only one file that each process shares.

Comment: It's possible, just pass around a handle to the filename along with the data that came from it. That way you can write to the correct file from a thread when the subprocess completes.

Comment: Is there some useful way your sub-processes can delay their IO while still doing useful work? Because if not, I'd guess that just letting them compete for the disk is likely to work better than any IO scheduling you could easily write yourself. If the disk contention really is too great, just start fewer subprocesses and you won't lose any performance (since your problem has turned out to be more IO-limited than CPU limited).

Comment: @Blckknght They're doing a significant amount of "busy work" (i.e., copying temporary data to the permanent info file when an iteration is accepted, and a LOT of it for analysis purposes while we're exploring the MCMC parameters for research), so spinning this off into a dedicated process might be worth while. I worry that the process might write over the temp files while they're waiting in the queue though.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no general answer here. What is your underlying file system? What exactly are the I/O needs? Reads, writes, small random access, large sequential, many small files, few large files, many folders?